# How do I change intellij idea to compile with scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea 13.1.4. I have a scala sbt project. It is currently being compiled with Scala 2.10. I would like to change this to Scala 2.11. In my build.sbt, I have:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.0",
  ...
)
```

When I build my project, it still builds as a Scala 2.10 project.

Also, under my `Project Settings->Modules->Scala->Facet 'Scala'->Compiler library`, Intellij still shows `scala-compiler-bundle:2.10.2`. There is no option for a `2.11.x` bundle. How would I get an option for Scala 2.11.x?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to point intellij to your scala 2.11 folder, wether you have it into the project or in a separated folder.

Comment: Update your scala version in build.sbt: scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

Comment: @EndeNeu How do I do that?

Comment: @RafalFoltynski I already have that line in my build.sbt.

Comment: Did you run 'Invalidate Caches/Restart..' option in File?  Some changes in build.sbt did not take effect for me util I run that option.

Comment: I think @RafalFoltynski is right, after setting `scalaVersion := "2.11.0"` you need to refresh sbt from inside intellij and go back to the compiler library option, you should be able to see the scala 2.11 compiler.

Comment: @RafalFoltynski Invalidating and restarting didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a reliable method for checking whether it's working? I like to run a main that prints util.Properties.versionString ... running Idea 13.1.4 on Os X I'm able to switch back and forth between 2.10.4 and 2.11.0 using the suggestion from @RafalFoltynski without clearing any caches (a trivial project that does nothing *but* printing the version).

Comment: If you use worksheets there is an option, to use a separate process, if that's disabled it seems to use the runtime that was used to build the IDE. I'm not shure if the guess with the build version is correct, but it happened to me that scala 2.10 was used before I did this change.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov I have a reliable way of checking whether it's working. I added a `println(scala.util.Properties.versionString)` and it gives me `version 2.10.4`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm also using the Play framework version 2.2.

Comment: I don't need to add the scald-compiler explicitly like you do, at all. The `scalaVersion := ...` is enough.

Answer (score 41):

In IntelliJ 2016.x you upgrade Scala by

Ensure Scala Plugin up to date.

Then by going to:

> File | Other Settings | Default Project Structure | Global Libraries

Click the `+` button at the top left hand side of the Window

Select `Scala SDK`

Choose the version you want to install.

Comment: When I try this, no file explorer shows up. Therefore I can't pick the version.

Comment: You'll need to have installed the latest version of Scala, On MacOS or Linux use Brew. Then the "Scala SDK" should show up.

Comment: This is how to add a scala SDK, but there is no button "Use this one as default". There is no indication which one is the currently used one.

Comment: IntelliJ 2016.x/2017.x allows you to select the SDK to add. From Project Structure | Global Libraries | + | Scala SDK. Then select (from the ones you have installed) the version you want.

Answer (score 11):

I have had the same issue as you. I added scala version 2.11 in my `build.sbt`.
After that, I removed the default scala SDK by

- Go to `File > Other Settings > Default Project Structures > Platform Settings > Global Libraries`
- Remove `scala-sdk-2.10.6`

Hence, IntelliJ will pick up my project scala SDK (after I do `sbt assembly`)

Answer (score 8):

As of intelliJ version: 2021.1.1 go to:

`File->Project structure->Platform settings->Global libraries`

press "+" and add/download Scala sdk

Answer (score 7):

In .iml file, there is entry for scala sdk library as shown below:

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="scala-sdk-2.10.6" level="application" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="scala-sdk-2.11.8" level="application" />
```

comment or remove the scala sdk version entry that you dont want.

Comment: this works for me! thanks! just clarify, on my IJ 2019.3 the .iml file is .idea/modules/[ProjectName].iml

Answer (score 2):

add this to your build.sbt file

`scalaVersion='2.11.11'`

Comment: This + relaunch your IDE

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add first a new scala-compiler in
File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure…

In scala-compiler include:

```
<SCALA_HOME>/lib/scala-compiler.jar
<SCALA_HOME>/lib/scala-library.jar
<SCALA_HOME>/lib/scala-reflect.jar
```

Replace  with your scala installation directory.

Go to File > Project Settings… and select the newly created compiler-library in "Compiler library". You may have to select Scala 2.11 in Language Level as well.